# $\infty$-topos and localic $\infty$-groupoids?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory, locales, infinity-categories

It's known that every classical (Grothendieck) topos is equivalent to the topos of sheaves on a localic groupoid (a groupoid in the category of locales).

For the record, this is proved by, starting form a topos $T$, constructing a locale $L$ and a surjection $L \rightarrow T$ 'nice enough' (like a proper surjection, or an open surjection depending on the proof).  Then $(L, L \times_T L, L \times_T L \times_T L)$ is a truncated simplicial locale, which can be seen as a localic groupoid. There is a canonical geometric morphism from the topos of sheaves on this groupoid to $T$, and if the surjection $L \rightarrow T$ was nice enough it's an isomorphism.

My question is : Can we hope for a similar result for $\infty$-toposes ? for example by replacing localic groupoids by a localic $\infty$-groupoids, defined as a simplicial locale satisfying some form of Kan complex condition and defining the associated $\infty$-topos as the colimits of the corresponding simplicial diagram of localic $\infty$-toposes.

Comment: This is something I have thought about in the back of my head for several years. If you come up with something, or would just like to brainstorm, let me know.

Comment: If I found any things about this, I will. But for now I have a lot of thing to learn before...

Comment: So, you're asking if every classical $\infty$-topos is equivalent to the category of sheaves on a localic $\infty$-topos, correct?

Comment: Do we have a hyperconnected-localic fact system?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Probably - but as far as I remember it hasn't been written (from what I remember Lurie in HTT talks about n-localic toposes but does not study the relative version)

Comment: @SimonHenry I think that would be a very good starting point to prove the result you want.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti  the stability under pullback of localic morphisms might be useful at some point yes. But the crucial point would be some form of Diaconescu Localic open cover theorem for $\infty$-toposes (though "open" should probably be replaced by locally $\infty$-connected or something like that...).

Comment: @SimonHenry In classical topos theory, the Diaconescu localic cover theorem gives a connected locally connected geometric morphism. Often people only stress on the fact that it is open.